# Postfix, Courier POP3 root account receiving all mail

Tags: postfix, pop3, courier

I have installed Postfix and Courier pop3 on Ubunto Hardy. I setup MX record to point to the server I built and it is working to some extend. I can email root@myFQDN.com from outlook and it works OK. I can receive email at root@myFQDN.com as well via outlook. I created an account for webmaster@myFQDN.com, the home directory /home/webmaster was created and is owned by 'webmaster webmaster'. I then did the 'maildirmake Maildir' command from the webmaster account and home directory. The directories new, cur and tmp are created under Maildir so everything is looking good. I then tried to send mail to webmaster@myFQDN.com and the email ended up at root@myFQDN.com mailbox.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is webmaster an alias for root in `/etc/aliases` ?

Comment: yes! Simple when you know how isn't it! I think I will havbe a steep learning curve for a few days! Thanks TiZon!